# Scraping with BeautifulSoup and JSON getting different result than expected

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape the following page:
http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=archiveheadlines&cat_id=105

using the following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"Referer": "http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=archiveheadlines&cat_id=105"}
data = {"id":2,"cat_id": 105, "method":"BL_NewsListing.GetCurrentHeadlinesPageData","params":"[]","version":"1.1"}
url = "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/RPCHandler.axd"
req = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
result = req.json()['result']
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')

print(table)
```

As a result I receive the data from page:
http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=currentheadlines
This is slightly different from the targeted outcome. Since it does not show all data from the targeted outcome I'm looking for a solution.

I tried adjusting the "method" from BL_NewsListing.GetCurrentHeadlinesPageData
to BL_NewsListing.GetArchiveHeadlinesPageData

But that does not work on my side at all. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "Referer": "http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=archiveheadlines&cat_id=105"
}

data = {
    "id": 2,
    "method": "BL_NewsListing.GetArchiveHeadlinesPageData",
    "params": "[\"105\",2023,0]",
    "version": "1.1"
}

url = "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/RPCHandler.axd"
req = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
result = req.json()["result"]
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table")

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             Date          Market    Alert #                                                                                                                                                         Headline
0    Mar 31, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-196                                                                                             Information regarding the redemption of TCV Acquisition Corp. (TCVA)
1    Mar 31, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-195                                                   Information Regarding the Reverse Stock Split and CUSIP Number Change for China Natural Resources, Inc. (CHNR)
2    Mar 30, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-194       Information Regarding the Business Combination of DiamondHead Holdings Corp. (DHHC/W/U) and Great Southern Homes, Inc. (Re-named United Homes Group, Inc.)
3    Mar 30, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-193                                                  Information Regarding the Reverse Stock Split, Name, Symbol & CUSIP Number Change for Helbiz, Inc. (HLBZ/HLBZW)
4    Mar 30, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-192                                                       Information Regarding the Reverse Stock Split and CUSIP Number Change for Ensysce Biosciences, Inc. (ENSC)
5    Mar 29, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-191                                                                        Information regarding the redemption of Aries I Acquisition Corporation (RAM/RAMMU/RAMMW)
6    Mar 29, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-190                                                  Information Regarding the Business Combination of Maxpro Capital Acquisition Corp. (JMAC/W/U) & Apollomics Inc.
7    Mar 29, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-189                                                         Information Regarding the Reverse Stock Split , Ratio and CUSIP Number Changes for Biophytis S.A. (BPTS)
8    Mar 28, 2023          NASDAQ  #2023-188                                                                 (UPDATED: Merger Effective) Information Regarding the Merger of AgroFresh Solutions, Inc. (AGFS)

...
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thnx for your help, it works like a charm.